# Even though postname is selected for permalink default keeps showing

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Wordpress - I have an issue where my selected permalink in settings is post name but when viewing my posts it is showing the default however pages are not affected. Any ideas how to make posts stay as www.website.com/pagename?

Answer (score 0):

stumbled upon the error which was the plugin Cybersyn, deactivated it and post name permalinks worked